# what is the meaning of this error "out of memory" when using picturebox1.Image equal to image FromFile(fileName)?

Tags: c#

I have a problem now with displaying an image from an exist file ...

```
try
{   
    bool EndFlag = false;
    string fileLoc = @"../../../../samples/jpeg_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + ".jpg";
    //Create a file Stream to save the body of the JPEG File content.
    FileStream fs = null;
    fs = new FileStream(fileLoc, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

    do 
    {
        ReadJpegFileCommand(); 
        CamPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
        CamPort.DiscardInBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            header[i] = (byte)CamPort.ReadByte();

         if (((int)header[0] == 0x76) && (header[1] == 0x00) && (header[2] == 0x32) && (header[3] == 0x00) && (header[4] == 0x00))
             {
                for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                        ImageBody[i] = (byte)CamPort.ReadByte();
              /* 
                 * writing the bytes that have been read till now to a file 
              */                    

                    fs.Write(ImageBody, 0, ImageBody.Length);

                    for (int i = 1; i < ImageBody.Length; i++)     // check if reached to the last two bytes(FF D9) of the body to  stop reading the body.
                    {
                        if ((ImageBody[i - 1] == 0xFF) && (ImageBody[i - 0] == 0xD9))
                        {
                            EndFlag = true;
                            MessageBox.Show("FFD9 has been received");
                            OneSnap.Image =(Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
                            fs.Close();

                        }
                    }
             }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Error,Try again"); // The first 5 bytes does not match the header 

         }


         for (int i = 0; i < footer.Length; i++)
         {
             footer[i] = (byte)CamPort.ReadByte();
         }



         // update the starting address 

         M += (UInt16)ImageBody.Length;
         //Progress.PerformStep();


        }while(!EndFlag);


    }



catch (System.Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```

When I have used this statements :

```
OneSnap.Image =(Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
                                                            fs.Close();
```

I had this error : "Parameter is not valid"

but when I've tried with alternative way and replaced the previous statements by ::

```
 fs.Close();
OneSnap.Image =(Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileLoc);
```

I showed  the image in the picture box .. but then when I have executed the program more I had this error :: " Out of memory " and couldn't see the image in the picture box (OneSnap) >>> How to solve this ??

sample :: ( this image has been captured by link Sprite Jpeg Camera )

[image]

Comment: Endless loop, nothing to do with the image file. Add some sanity check to your loop, e.g. break if more than 1000000 iterations.

Comment: I've succeeded to store the image bytes in the file stream >>
but I want to display this image in the windows form application!
I don't understand what do u mean by endless loop >>
can u clarify more ?

Comment: using Image.FromFile(fileLoc);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the file you created is not a valid picture, so can't be converted to a Bitmap.

See the [official docuemtation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Exception             Condition
-------------------------------
OutOfMemoryException  The file does not have a valid image format.
                      -or-
                      GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.
```

Can't see a way to "fix" this, but you can verify by trying to view the file in picture viewer; if you can view it then you might need something more complex than what System.Drawing offers.

Edit: might be easier than any of us imagined. Try changing the order of your lines:

```
fs.Close();
OneSnap.Image =(Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
```

Might be that while the stream is open, the Bitmap internal code can't read from the file.

Another approach is using MemoryStream instead. For this, first add a List to store all the bytes:

```
List<byte> arrAllBytes = new List<byte>();
```

Now instead of this line:

```
fs.Write(ImageBody, 0, ImageBody.Length);
```

Have this code:

```
arrAllBytes.AddRange(ImageBody);
```

And finally:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(arrAllBytes.ToArray())
OneSnap.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: Ooh! .. but I can see the file in that location after closing the file stream by the image viewer !!

Comment: How can I solve this problem ??

Is it possible to use another way to display the image from the file stream ???

Comment: Can you please upload sample picture into your question? (you have "Image" icon in the editor)

Comment: See my edit. Did you try closing the stream first then use it?

Comment: :(

I've tried with this and I've got this exception :

Parameter is not valid !!

Comment: Sorry, no further ideas. Are you sure that image you uploaded is result of your code?

Comment: See my edit. If this one doesn't help then I'm truly out of ideas. :-/

Comment: this is true .. but I need to store all the image bytes in the same array "ImageBody" not only this 32 bytes because the camera store the hole image bytes in its buffer and when I send read jpeg file contents command it send to me the data in this format header+body+footer >> the body consists of 32 bytes it send me the data as chunks each chunk size are an integer times of 8 , this command should be sent many times until FFD9 received which indicates the end of the jpeg bytes >> 
if I want to use memory stream I have to store all the jpeg bytes in the same array >> Is this true ??

Comment: this is the manual :
http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Imaging/1274419957.pdf

Comment: Yeah sorry, missed that. You can store all the bytes in a list, see my edit.

Comment: Thank u so much >> I will try with this I hope I can get the result that I want :(

Thanks ^____^